# Add loader to particular component which is pressed rather than all other button component in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have 2 buttons component, I want the loader to a particular button that is clicked.

Here is my code

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function ProductDetail() {
  const [adding, setAdding] = useState(false);

  const buttonClicked =() => {
    setAdding(true)
    .
    .

  }
  return (
           .
           .
           <div>
            <button>{ adding ? "Please wait..." : "Add to Cart"}</button>
            <button>{ adding ? "Please wait..." : "Buy Now"}</button>
          </div>
          .
          .
   );
}
```

But in this case, both buttons get Please wait... when I click on one of them.
I want a loader to that button that is clicked
How can I get that

**Note: I don't want to create multiple states**

Answer (score 1):

Does this help:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const LoadingStateTest = () => {
  const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState({
    "add-to-cart": false,
    "buy-now": false,
  });

  const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
    const targetId = e.target.id;
    const isBuying = targetId === "buy-now";

    setLoadingState({
      "add-to-cart": !isBuying,
      "buy-now": isBuying,
    });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button id="add-to-cart" name="Add to Cart" onClick={handleButtonClick}>
        {loadingState["add-to-cart"] ? "Please wait..." : "Add to Cart"}
      </button>
      <button id="buy-now" name="Buy Now" onClick={handleButtonClick}>
        {loadingState["buy-now"] ? "Please wait..." : "Buy Now"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoadingStateTest;
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, But what in case I have 10 such buttons

Comment: If you have more buttons just externalize the loadingState object, put it into an external file and just use all the values from there. In the click handler just set all the values not equal to the current id to false. Object.keys will return all keys from the object, and you can use the keys to detect value changes.